# Cambiar el título de un item de la barra de menú

Tags: swift

Quiero cambiar el título de los items de la barra de menú.

He intentado lo siguiente:

- Creo un IBOutlet del MenuItem que quiero cambiar
- Cambio el título
- Lanzo una notificación

El código es:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var formato: NSMenuItem!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        let barraMenu = NSApp.mainMenu
        
        self.formato.title = "Formato"
        
        // Lanza una notificación
        let centroDeNotificaciones = NotificationCenter.default
        //centroDeNotificaciones.post(name: NSMenu.didChangeItemNotification, object: formato)
        centroDeNotificaciones.post(name: NSMenu.didChangeItemNotification, object: barraMenu!, userInfo: ["NSMenuItemIndex":NSNumber(value: 3)])
        }
}
```

Parece que el título se ha cambiado pero no se muestra cuando se lanza la aplicación.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: y has probado con self.title ?

Comment: Cómo conectaste el `IBOutlet` desde el AppDelegate al Interface Builder de Xcode?

Comment: ¡Gracias por contestar! El IBOutlet se hace desde el menú de la ventana del mainstoryboard a AppDelegate; y los cambios en el método applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Comment: No es recomendable usar el appdelagate para cambiar estados de iboutlet, en lugar de eso revisa el controller del view que deseas cambiar.

Answer (score 0):

¡Gracias por contestar!

El IBOutlet se hace desde el menú de la ventana del mainstoryboard a AppDelegate; y los cambios en el método applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Ya he resuelto el problema: lo que yo cambiaba era el título del NSMenuItem del mainMenu, mientras que lo que se muestra en la barra de menús es el título del submenú de cada item del mainMenu. Lo que hay que hacer es:

`self.formato.submenu!.title = "Formato"`

Saludos de Víctor.-